# Instantiating classes between jsp scriptlets

Tags: jsp, class, instantiation, scriptlet

Is it possible to instantiate a class and then invoke its methods between scriptlets in JSP?
I am getting errors and I don't know why (java class and methods are fine).
Any other way to do the same (i just want a string from a method in a class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of-course. You can create objects for your classes and access their methods between scriptlets in JSP like this.

```
<%
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     foo.method1();
%>
```

Another way of doing this is using useBeans of jsp to instantiate the class and access its method in scriptlet

```
<jsp:useBean id = "foo" class = "Foo" />
<%
     foo.method1();
%>
```

Comment: OK thanks.
I thought beans are only used on submitting and they may only include getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the page import in the header like so:

```
<%@ page import="sample.Foo" %>
```