# serial port reader java

Tags: java, serial-port

I have a problem in executing serial port reader code in jsp.The thing while am running the simple reader class alone then am able to read the values.When this class is initiated from a jsp inorder to call the reader.But it is not getting executed

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; //import gnu.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.comm.*;

public class SimpleRead1 implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static Enumeration portList;

    InputStream inputStream;
    SerialPort serialPort;
    Thread readThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    String temperature;
    String pressure;
    int count=0;

    public String getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(String temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public String getPressure() {
        return pressure;
    }

    public void setPressure(String pressure) {
        this.pressure = pressure;
    }

    public void SimpleRead5()
    {
        System.out.println("Simpleread5");
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        System.out.println(portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers());
        System.out.println(portList.hasMoreElements());
           /* try {
                System.out.println("portList... " + CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM5"));
            } catch (NoSuchPortException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SimpleRead.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }*/
        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                System.out.println("port identified is Serial.. "
                        + portId.getPortType());
                if (portId.getName().equals("COM5")) {
                    System.out.println("port identified is COM4.. "
                            + portId.getName());
                    // if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
                    SimpleRead1 reader = new SimpleRead1();
                    reader.SimpleRead4();

                } else {
                    System.out.println("unable to open port");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void SimpleRead4() {
        try {
            System.out.println("In SimpleRead() contructor");
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp1111",500);
            System.out.println(" Serial Port.. " + serialPort);
        } catch (PortInUseException e) {
            System.out.println("Port in use Exception");
        }
        try {
            inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
            System.out.println(" Input Stream... " + inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception");
        }
        try {
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);

        } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
            System.out.println("Tooo many Listener exception");
        }
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        try {

            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // no handshaking or other flow control
            serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

            // timer on any read of the serial port
            serialPort.enableReceiveTimeout(500);

            System.out.println("................");


        } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
            System.out.println("UnSupported comm operation");
        } 
        readThread = new Thread(this);
        readThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("In run() function ");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            // System.out.println();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted Exception in run() method");
        }
    }

    String dataType="";
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

        // System.out.println("In Serial Event function().. " + event +
        // event.getEventType());
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
        /*
         * case SerialPortEvent.BI: case SerialPortEvent.OE: case
         * SerialPortEvent.FE: case SerialPortEvent.PE: case SerialPortEvent.CD:
         * case SerialPortEvent.CTS: case SerialPortEvent.DSR: case
         * SerialPortEvent.RI: case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY: break;
         */
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
            readBuffer = new byte[8];

            try {

                while (inputStream.available()>0) {

                    int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                //   System.out.println("Number of bytes read " + numBytes);
                }

                String serialdata=new String(readBuffer);
                if(serialdata.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
                    dataType="a";
                }else if(serialdata.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
                    dataType="b";
                }else{
                    if(dataType=="a"){

                        System.out.println("Temperature :"+serialdata.trim());
                        temperature=serialdata.trim();
                        setTemperature(temperature);
                        count++;
                    }else if(dataType=="b"){

                        System.out.println("Pressure :"+serialdata.trim());
                        pressure=serialdata.trim();
                        setPressure(pressure);
                        count++;
                    }

                }
                if(count==2)
                {
                    System.out.println(getTemperature()+getPressure()); 
                        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(false);


                }

               // System.out.println(new String(readBuffer));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IO Exception in SerialEvent()");
            }
            break;
        }
        // System.out.println();
    /*  String one = new String(readBuffer);
        char two = one.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Character at three: " + two);*/
    }

}
```

Comment: The result of a jsp is a web page that shows in a browser.  You are not in the server, you are in the browser.  You need to read the serial port before you return the html code to the browser?

Comment: is there any way to use this serial port reader in jsp?

Comment: The jsp is intended to return HTML to a browser.  The jsp can execute java code, you only need to instantiate  class SimpleRead1.  But who returns this jsp could also instantiate this class, and give to the jsp the results.

Comment: but i have instantiated this reader class in another java class .

Comment: Your jsp don't need to access to the serial port, only need the values readed from it.  This class has to give this values to the jsp.

Comment: still i want to instantiate that class from jsp rite?

Comment: Ok, I hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889018/instantiating-classes-between-jsp-scriptlets

Comment: yeah i have done that too.But it is returning false while checking the port.When am running the class alone it is returning true

Comment: Then you need to debug.  Put a breakpoint in the SimpleRead1 class, and see if each variable has the value expected.

Comment: yeah i have checked it by debugging also.Till that while condition the program goes correcrtly.When it comes to the while(portlist.hasmoreelements()) it returns false and program execution stops

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955530/commportidentifier-getportidentifiers-is-empty.  Perhaps you have to add some library to the web application than have the jsp.

Comment: yeah i have added all those unzipped files in the jre folders properly.And the program executes while running that  class alone.When accessing that class from jsp it goes wrong

Comment: I can't help then.  I hope someone else could helpt to you.  I'm sorry.  :-(

Comment: You could show the jsp also.

Comment: I suggest to change the name of `SimpleRead5()` and `SimpleRead4()`.  They seem constructors, but you class name is `SimpleRead1`.  You could name them in lowercase.